# Search.messages help withPython SDK

Tags: python, webclient, slack-api

I am trying to use the Slack Python SDK to search for messages. My call looks like this:

```
result = CLIENT.api_call(
            api_method="search.messages",
            json={"query": search_phrase,
                  "count": limit,
                  "page": current_page,
                  "highlights": highlights
                  }
        )
```

But my result is:

```
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'invalid_arguments', 'response_metadata': {'messages': ['[ERROR] missing required field: query']}}
```

As you can see, the call does include the "query" parameter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Dan